# How to split a json string value by character into some substrings in Apache Nifi

Tags: json, split, apache-nifi, jolt

i have a json file like the schema below and want to split the value of the key 'adress' by a character (for example a comma):

```json
{
  "id": 123,
  "name": "James",
  "adress": "Oxford Street,21,London,England"
}
```

and convert it to the following (-> split the adress field by comma into these fields):

```json
{
  "id": 123,
  "name": "James",
  "street": "Oxford Street",
  "house number": "21",
  "city": "London",
  "country": "England"
}
```

I found a solution in internet (http://ostack.cn/?qa=94733/), where someone splits their attibute into 2 key/values (with the jolt-processor) and it worked for me as well, but not for more than this split.

The processor could be 'Jolt Transform' or any with which i can edit json like in the schema above.

Thanks for the help, Lukas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **split** function along with **modify-overwrite-beta** spec within **JoltTransformJSON** processor such as

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "@(0,adress)": "adr",
      "*": "&"
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "adr": "=split(',', @(1,&))",
      "street": "@(1,adr[0])",
      "house number": "@(1,adr[1])",
      "city": "@(1,adr[2])",
      "country": "@(1,adr[3])"
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "remove",
    "spec": {
      "adr": "",
      "adress": ""
    }
  }
]
```

where the shift spec stands for generating the array(`adr`) to be processed through use of **split**, and **remove** is for deleting the unwanted key-value pairs.

[image]